# Объявление структур в c\c++

Tags: c++

Помогите мне,пожалуйста избавиться от непонимания объявления классов и структур в с\с++.

Есть некое объявление структуры(Как я понимаю чистое си):

```
typedef struct StructName
{
    int a,b,c;

} Name;
```

Так вот зачем писать StructName,и можно ли вообще,если у нас синтаксис typedef:

*typedef тип имя;*

Так вот вот у нас получается что тип это "struct StructName"?
Разве не правильней было написать?:

```
typedef struct
    {
        int a,b,c;

    } Name;
```

**Если и тот и тот вариант правильный,в чем отличие?**

И если мы хотим создать 1-n количество структур в объявлении как писать?
В с++ вроде можно так:

```
struct StructName
   {
    int a,b,c;

   } str1,srt2,str3;
```

И унас уже создано 3 структуры  str1,srt2,str3.
Но как это на Си сделать?

Comment: вы же сами ответили на свой вопрос.

Comment: AR Hovsepyan в каком месте я ответил на свой вопрос?